# Eigen parameters passing by reference

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3, pybind11

I'm following this page in the Eigen documentation an trying to understand the use of Eigen parameters

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

The following code works as expected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

// a - nonwriteable, b - writeable
void eigen_reference_class(
    const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Array<double, 
    Eigen::Dynamic, 3> >& a, Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3> > b) {
    b = 2 * a;
}

void eigen_reference(const Eigen::Array<double, 1, 3>& a, Eigen::Array<double, 1, 3>& b) {
    b = 2*a;
}

template<typename Derived> 
void eigen_template(const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>& a, Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>& b) {
    b = 2*a;
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::Array<double, 1, 3> a, b, c, d;
    a << 1, 2, 3;
    eigen_reference_class(a, b);
    eigen_reference(a, c);
    eigen_template(a,  d);
    std::cout << "a : \n" << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: \n" << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c: \n" << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d: \n" << d << std::endl;

}
```

However, if the initial declaration for the arrays is changed to

```
Eigen::Array<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3> a, b, c, d;
```

Then the program will either fail to compile with the following:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Eigen::Array<double, 1, 3>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Eigen::Array<double, 1, 3>’       
     eigen_reference(a, c);
```

Or will fail with a segmentation fault even if only the definition of `a` is kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like looking at what `int` does in such situations because it helps me understand the more complex things happening in this case easier.

Imagine you have a `struct` holding an `int` which is implicitly convertible to an `int`, so that you can use it in place of an `int`, like so:

```
struct Integer {
    int m_int;
    operator int() { return m_int; }
};
```

Now define two functions, one taking an `int const &` and one taking an `int &`.

```
void const_ref(int const &) {}
void ref(int &) {}
```

If we use a regular integer in those functions, there are no suprises.

```
int j = 3;
const_ref(j);
ref(j);
```

But if we use `Integer` instead it does not compile anymore.

```
Integer i{2};
const_ref(i);
ref(i);
```

The error is something like

```
error: no matching function for call to 'ref'
    ref(i);
    ^~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Integer' to 'int &' for 1st argument
void ref(int &) {}
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Now the question is, why does `const_ref` work but `ref` doesn't?

In the call to `const_ref` what happens is that the conversion operator to `int` is called, which returns a temporary `int` to which we can bind a constant reference.  We cannot bind a mutable reference to this temporary because this would lead to weird effects.  Imagine that the function `ref` modifies the argument, but in this case it would modify a temporary and nothing would be written to the original `Integer` which you passed in... a guaranteed bug.

---

In your code it's the same.  `Eigen::Array<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3>` can implicitly convert to `Eigen::Array<double, 1, 3>` but you cannot bind a mutable reference to a temporary.